# Rule to delete other node of same type before saving content

Tags: rules

I have designed one content type which can be created by registered users via "Form Block" Module. I am now trying to create a rule which will allow each user to only have one existing node of that content type. If they decide to create a node of that content type again, the previous node should be deleted.

I'm having trouble with the rule that would accomplish this. There are no errors, but nothing appears to be being deleted.

**Event** =

```
Before saving content
```

**Conditions =**

```
Content is of type (Parameter: Content: [node], Content types: NeuroTrans pt1)

Data comparison (Parameter: Data to compare: [node:author:uid], Data value: [site:current-user:uid])
```

**Action** =

```
Delete entity (Parameter: Entity: [node])
```

Here's an export of the rule that I have created:

```
{ "rules_delete_previous_neuro_pt1" : {
"LABEL" : "Delete current user\u0027s previous NeuroTrans pt1",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : [ "node_presave" ],
"IF" : [
  { "node_is_of_type" : {
      "node" : [ "node" ],
      "type" : { "value" : { "neurotrans_pt1" : "neurotrans_pt1" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:author:uid" ], "value" : [ "site:current-user:uid" ] } }
],
"DO" : [ { "entity_delete" : { "data" : [ "node" ] } } ]
```

}
}

**Using the "code" entry mode for this post doesn't appear to preserve the formatting quite perfectly.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you set on using rules? Have you considered writing a custom module - you can do this with a bit of coding.

Comment: When it comes to coding, I'm like a dolphin trying to cross the desert - it's really not a pretty sight. Rules, at least, is almost within my ability to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel,

What I think is happening is that you're trying to delete the actual node that the user is about to save (it hasn't been saved yet)!

It doesn't look like you're finding the user's PREVIOUS node to delete first, you're just trying to work with the current one.  :-)

Of course - since this current node hasn't even been saved yet (your event is prior to saving), there is nothing to be deleted.

The rule will have to be more complicated, with your finding an existing node by the current user first...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Boriana. I will look for a way to do that. I was trying to make a rule  that would delete any node of that type, if created by that user, before saving the new content - with the result being that there would only ever be one node of that type by that user. I will attempt to switch my logic to your method.

Comment: Yes, try to switch it around.  Otherwise, what you're doing now is leaving the old node and attempting to delete the one they're just about to save (which you can't because it hasn't been saved yet).  Let us know what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. I found my answer in [THIS HELPFUL VIDEO](http://drupalize.me/videos/sync-article-promotions-articles). In addition to what I described above, only two other components were required to be added to the "actions" section of my rule. The actions section should look like:

Actions:

**Fetch entity by property** :
Parameter: Entity type: Node, Property: Content type, Value: [node:type] Provides variables: Fetched entity (entity_fetched)

**Loop** : 
Parameter: List: [entity-fetched]
List item: Current list item (list_item)

--(added to loop)--**Delete entity** : 
Parameter: Entity: [entity-fetched:0]

Comment: Yep! That should do it. Glad you got on the right track and got it working!